# How to build a Cordova app to windows 10 (universal)

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, win-universal-app, ripple

I'm currently developing a Cordova application with jQuery Mobile by using sublime text 3 and using Ripple to emulate my devices (I'll reference this project as **SublimeProject**).

I can build apps for IOS, Android and Win8. But now I need to build it for Windows 10. Apparently this doesn't work with my setup.

A colleague of mine told me to import the project in Visual Studio (I'll reference this as **VSProject**), add the plugins in the config.xml, copy over the files to the www folder and run it. Problem here is that it just doesn't work. 
When I try to run it on Android with the `Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy)` emulator, it'll give me a warning like this:

```
I Haz CHeeseburger?!?!
PushPlugin.register

We seem to be missing some stuff :(

What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute
Success!    Fail!
```

But when I press `Fail!` the program will just work, somehow.
My console shows me the following for ripple.js:

```
ripple.js:37 Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.)
ripple.js:51 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ripple.js:51 GET http://localhost:4400/config.xml 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ ripple.js:51module.exports.initialize @ ripple.js:51_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13xhr.onreadystatechange @ ripple.js:39
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Native back button handler was detached.
ripple.js:41 missing exec:PushPlugin.register
ripple.js:48 PushPlugin
ripple.js:48 register
```

Makes sense that something is wrong with `pushplugin`, but can't figure out what.

Additional, when I try to run the application on Windows-AnyCPU (which my actual intent is), the application will just show me the default cordova splash screen and hang there:

[image]

So that's where I'm at. I need to figure out a way to get the app to run on Windows 10. Prefered to use Visual Studio because I know it has an option to build me an `.xap` file.

### Updates:

## Update 1

I'm tracing where the PushPlugin error comes from.

```
try {
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
}
```

pushNotification seems to be undefined, yet in my config.xml I have the following line:
`<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />`

## Update 2

The pushplugin doesn't seem to be relevant, because when debugging in Visual Studio, I'll find the pushNotification to be **not** undefined.
Currently there is nothing pointing to a good reason why I only see the splash screen instead of my application.

Comment: Can you give me a basic example project through github or onedrive,which can reproduce your problem?So that I can help you further.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the problem here. But I just discovered the possible reason for my problem. In my www folder I have an index.html that has a `window.location = './main.html';` piece of code. When it passes that, the application crashes. Is there a valid reason why Cordova can't handle a `window.location` request?

Comment: I made a basic demo, which uses a button to handle window.location='./main.html'; It didn't crash on Ripple and windows. I think there are some other reasons that causes your App's crash.

Comment: But it is recommanded that you make your app a Single Page Application see [SPA is Your Friend](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/next/#1-spa-is-your-friend)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out it was due to duplicate url in the $stateProvider.